# How to increate vuetify data table font-size?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a a child component with a data-table. But the font-size of DOM inside the child component gets small. I'm trying to see if there a way to to increase the font-size of my data-table header and th. If there is also away to make to make the child component to keep the same font-size as the parent or grand-parent component.

I tried `header {font-size:15px}` and `th {font-size:12x}` inside the child component and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Child component define your custom style in `style scope` has showing below:

```
<style scoped>
  .v-data-table header {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

 .v-data-table th {
   font-size: 12px;
 }

 .v-data-table td {
   font-size: 12px;
 }
</style>
```